# Looking to easily track changes/differences from a weekly report

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking to track changes from a weekly report in comparison to the previous week.

For example week 1 has the following orders outstanding

```
1A
1B
1C
1D
```

Week 2 has the following orders outstanding

```
1C
1D
1E
1F
```

As you can see 1C & 1D are outstanding in both weeks, 1A & 1B have both been closed, and 1E & 1F are new outstanding orders.

Is their an easy way to track the number of closed orders and number of new orders in comparison to last weeks report?

Comment: What tool do you use? is it a text editor / spreadsheet??? What have you tried already? Why did you tagged your question as newline?

Comment: Using excel 2010

Comment: As Mat Juhans said, what have you tried already?

Comment: Have tried Vlookups and COUNTIF, but I gave up as I dont feel that either formulas are the correct ones to use, hence why I came on here. Thought that posting it without formulas would be more benefical as it might just confuse things.

Comment: Take a minute to read **[ask]**, and you will find out it is the opposite here. Because we are not a script/formula writing service, we actually want to know what you have tried and what you are working with. Can you tell us more about how the data is laid out. Are these tables on the same sheet, different sheets, different files?

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense, sorry for not reading them beforehand. In terms of the data it would be across two sheets, but I could put the data into one sheet if needed. It would mainly only be focusing on one column from each sheet as this would be the unique identification number to search against.

I guess in my head it sounded more simple than it really is. I will have two sheets one which is the latest update and one which is the old data. I wanted to look at how many have been closed out in comparison to the previous week and how many are new lines in comparison to the previous week